# Measuring speed of communications between processes

Tags: process, performance

```
Ubuntu 16.04
```

I have 2 processes which communicate between each other. The process `p1` writes data to stdout, the process `p2` in turn reads this data and does some processing.

The issue is it is all slow. I would like to understand which process is slow. `p1` slowly generates data so `p2` has to wait or `p2` generates data so fast so `p1` cannot process them as fast.

Are there some tools in linux to perform such measurment?